# Angularjs - custom directive with the same name of standard html elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

What happens if I create a directive that has the same name of standard html attributes or elements?
For example if I define:

```
.directive('link', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elements, attributes){
      // do something
   }
})
```

used like this

```
<a link="http://www.foo.com" ng-href="www.google.com">Conditional Link </a>
```

would it conflict with the standard `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">` element?

Maybe in this case it would not because I've restricted the directive to attributes only, but my question is more general.

For example what if I named my directive `href`?
Will the directives always have the precedence over the standard html element or attributes?

Comment: it should work as you will command it to; this is directive's purpose after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directives can attach behavior to existing html element. 
If you create directive href, i believe there should be no issue, unless your directive removes itself (or `href`). There is no concept of precedence unless multiple directives are defined or applied on same element.

Remember you cannot change the behavior of browser, if browser sees a href with a remote url it would make a request irrespective.

AngularJS itself uses `<input />` as a directive and it works fine with the standard input behavior intact.

Comment: I also use a match for `<input>` to attach behavior but I'm careful not to mess with angular unless i really wants to. so there is no conflict in having same directive name

Comment: So unless I use `replace : true` in general there should be no issue? If in my example I had used `restrict: 'E'` for the `link` directive, then in fact all the `<link>' elements in the application would appear as a custom directive? So they will use my custom behaviour but still the browser will make a standard use of them (unless I replace them), isn't it?

Comment: Yes, i think so. if it works for `input`, it should work for `link`. Why don't you give it a try and share your findings. Directives is a vocabulary defined by Angular, at the end everything is a html element or attribute.